# Is it safe to add a server-side header and use this value throughout the API for validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

In the below verifyToken function, I check if the token is valid, extract the ID in the token and assign it to a - new - req.user header.

I have two questions:

1. Can this, server-side added header, be spoofed using postman or custom code?
2. Should this req.user.id value be used in nodeJS code to validate ownership of data, before being able to edit/delete information? For example, to edit a user profile, I check if the req.user.id header is the same as the user profile ID in the database and then permit editing. Is this safe?

Function below:

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
const authHeader = req.headers.token;

try {
if (authHeader) {
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");
      console.log(`validation failed for token (${token}): ${err}`);
    } else {
       console.log("user validated");
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  });
}
 } catch (err) {
return res.status(401).json("You are not authenticated!");
}
 };
```

Comment: 1 depends on how token is signed 2 yes it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Postman and custom code run on the client-side, they don't have access to the server's secret key `process.env.JWT_SEC`.
2. `req.user.id` common and reasonable practice.

It's generally secure when the JWT token is accurately verified, and your authorization logic is robust.